# How add items to a list in foreach loop using c#

Tags: c#, list, foreach, dynamics-crm-2011

I am using following snippet to some items to a list of strings. But it is throwing an exception.

```
List<string> guids = null;
QueryExpression qExp = new QueryExpression
{
    EntityName = "account",
    ColumnSet = col1,
    Criteria = new FilterExpression
    {
        Conditions = { 
            new ConditionExpression("statecode",ConditionOperator.Equal,0)
        }
    }
};
sp.CallerId = g1;
EntityCollection ec1 = sp.RetrieveMultiple(qExp);
foreach (Entity item in ec1.Entities)
{
   guids.Add(Convert.ToString(item.Attributes["accountid"]));
}
```

**Exception:**
Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: You just need to instantiate your guids list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use LINQ:

```
List<string> guids = ec1.Entities
   .Select(entity => Convert.ToString(entity.Attributes["accountid"]))
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Can be done even shorter: `List<string> guids = ec1.Entities.Select(e => e.Id.ToString()).ToList();`

Comment: Yes, they are. "accountid" is the primary key field of entity account. The entity rows returned by RetrieveMultiple always contain the primary key, which is held by the Id property.

Comment: That's probably why I don't work with Dynamics CRM... B-)

Comment: It's actually a fine piece of software. Microsoft did a good job here. There are always things to improve, but that also applies to my own work.

Answer (score 2):

Change `List<string> guids = null;` to `List<string> guids = new List<string>();` and all will be well.

You must initialise the list before you can start writing to it. You are setting it to `null`, thus the exception.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `List<string> guids = null;`

Try to do `List<string> guids = new List<string>();`