# add items to a list in a foreach loop then return result from method

Tags: c#, foreach

Have hit a snag when trying to add objects to a list from within a foreach loop.
I have noted that this is a problematic approach in other posts however I am not seeing or understanding perhaps the best way around this.

I created the endpointObject class as shown below adapted from [this post](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/create-a-list-of-objects-in-C-Sharp/). This makes sense to me and works as expected.

```
public class endpointObject
{
    private string isHost;
    private string FTRname;
    private string ip;
    private string port;

    public endpointObject(string isHost, string FTRname, string ip, string port)
    {
        this.isHost = isHost;
        this.FTRname = FTRname;
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
        Console.WriteLine("endpointObject instantiated");
        lib.writeToLog("endpointObject instantiated");
    }

    public string _isHost
    {
        get { return isHost; }
        set { isHost = value; }
    }

    public string _FTRname
    {
        get { return FTRname; }
        set { FTRname = value; }
    }

    public string _ip
    {
        get { return ip; }
        set { ip = value; }
    }

    public string _port
    {
        get { return port; }
        set { port = value; }
    }

}
```

Below is called from another class. As previously mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204676/how-add-items-to-a-list-in-foreach-loop-using-c-sharp), it is not possible to add to a list from within a foreach loop.

"You will need to create a temporary list and do an AddRange() after."

^^ not sure how to go abut this ^^

and I get the following error, which I understand may be linked to not being able to add to a list in a foreach loop:

`{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}`:

```
    public List<endpointObject> init(string configPath)
    { 
        var configDoc = new XmlDocument();
        try
        {
            configDoc.Load(configPath);
        }
        catch
        {
        //catch exception
        }
        List<endpointObject> endpointItem = new List<endpointObject>();

        foreach (XmlNode node in configDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (node.Name == "endpoints" && node.HasChildNodes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Child Nodes of endpoints: " + node.ChildNodes.Count);
                foreach (XmlNode endP in node)
                {
                    endpointItem.Add(new endpointObject(endP.Attributes["isHost"].Value, endP.Attributes["name"].Value, endP.Attributes["ip"].Value, endP.Attributes["port"].Value));
                }
            }
        }  


        return endpointItem;
    }
```

As you will notice I am iterating over the returned nodes from xml.
Hopefully someone can help me understand a way around this limitation or explain how i should approach this differently.

My aim here is to be able to return the list objects from the method and have them be available for further manipulation outside of the init method

**EDIT 1**

When I add the following line into the foreach loop, it generates the correct output:

```
Console.WriteLine(endP.Attributes["isHost"].Value + ", " + endP.Attributes["FTRname"].Value + ", " + endP.Attributes["ip"].Value + ", " + endP.Attributes["port"].Value);
```

The output I see is:

```
true, PC01, --, --
```

Which is exactly what I expected. 
 It is the `endpointItem.Add(new endpointObject(` which is giving me grief and I am having trouble with.

**EDIT 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<system>
  <configItems>
    <configItem name="streamCode" value="fgghj85678gf" configItem="0">
      <!--customer streamCode, required for authenication on server-->
    </configItem>
    <configItem name="submissionURL" value="http://example.com" configItem="1">
      <!--Data Ingest URL-->
    </configItem>
    <configItem name="reportingInterval" value="30" configItem="1">
      <!--device Name-->
    </configItem>
  </configItems>
  <endpoints>
    <endpoint isHost="true" name="PC01" ip="--" port="--" recordActive="">
      <!--endpoint record entry, isHost configures local system to report both system hostname and configured name value-->
    </endpoint>
  </endpoints>
</system>
```

**EDIT 3**
Example xml attribute testing

```
              if (endP.Attributes["port"].Value != null)
                {
                    port = endP.Attributes["port"].Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    port = "NA";
                }
```

Comment: I believe either of your attributes is throwing the null reference exception. `endP.Attributes["isHost"] or endP.Attributes["name"] or endP.Attributes["ip"] or endP.Attributes["port"].Value`

Comment: You definitely CAN add to a list within a foreach loop. You just can't add / delete from the same list that you are enumerating with `foreach`. Step through a debugger to see where the null reference issue is - It's likely to be in the Xml parsing.

Comment: @StuartLC See update, issue is not in the Xml parsing as far as I can tell. From what I can gather the endpointObject  partof this is the issue, perhaps it is not visible from within the foreach loop?

Comment: @Majickal then it's your constructor which is crashing. `lib.writeToLog("endpointObject instantiated");` - `lib` is likely null or has a bug in `writeToLog` method.

Comment: @StuartLC it's definitely not the lib.writeToLog that has this issue. The `NullReferenceExaception was unhandled ` points to the last semicolon on the `endpointItem.Add....` line in the foreach loop. could there be a reason why `new endpointObject` section is not able to see the class to create a new instance of it?

Comment: Your code wouldn't compile if the class wasn't in scope. Can you edit your question with a sample of the Xml payload please.

Comment: @StuartLC xml is now up Edit 2

Comment: @StuartLC  I think the issue may be related to the endpointObject constructor not returning a value, which is why it also fails when dummy data is added to the endpointItem.Add ie `endpointItem.Add(new endpointObject("test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"));`

Comment: No, constructors do not have a return type. `new` returns the reference to the object, which can be added to your list. It is your `lib` which is broken. Comment out `lib.writeToLog(` out and try again. I have tested locally - your Xml parsing is fine (although fragile - if any attributes are missing, it will also NRE).